# Unable to write batch document in firestore collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My function receives data from a mobile app. When a CASHIN request is made, the function postIntouch sends a Https requests to a third party API then saves the current transaction in a Firestore collection as a unconfirmed transaction. while waiting for the third-party callback with the transaction status. When the callback is triggered, `enter code here`the function update the user balance by checking the user collection to find the correct transaction and update the status in the document and and then send it to the ledger. My problem is that the callback isn't able to update the correct user balance because the unconfirmed transaction isn't saved in the user collection.  Any help would be appreciated !

Check the callback sent by the third party.
Unable to find any trace on of the transaction in the collection

```js
/**
 * Logic to initiate a cash in/out operation
 * 
 * @param data
 * {
 *   ...
 *   provider: 'ORANGE' | 'TELMOB' | 'TELECEL',
 *   operation: 'CASHIN' | 'CASHOUT' | 'AIRTIME',
 *   amount: number,
 *   otp: string,
 *   ...
 * }
 * 
 * @returns code 200 on transaction pending
 *          In case of errors, return message '5-Insufficiant funds' or '8-Amount cannot be negative'
 */
exports.postIntouch = functions.https.onCall(async (
    data:
        {
            provider: _.IntouchProvider,
            operation: _.IntouchOperation,
            amount: number,
            email : string
            otp: string,
            clientTimestamp: string
        },
    context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'A user must be authenticated')
    }
    const { provider, operation, amount, otp,} = data

    /* PRELIMINARY VALIDATION */
    if (amount <= 0) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', `${_.Errors.negativeAmount.code}-${_.Errors.negativeAmount.message}`)
    if (_.INTOUCH_SERVICE[provider][operation].length === 0) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unimplemented', 'Service not available')

    /* FIND USER */
    const user = await _.findUser({ uid: context.auth.uid })
    if (user === undefined) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'Could not find user')

    /* IF CASHOUT OR AIRTIME OR BILL, MAKE SURE USER HAS ENOUGH FUNDS */
    if (operation === _.IntouchOperation.CASHOUT || operation === _.IntouchOperation.AIRTIME || operation === _.IntouchOperation.BILL) {
        if (user.wallet.fcfa < amount) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition',
            `${_.Errors.insufficiantFunds.code}-${_.Errors.insufficiantFunds.message}`
        )
    }

    /* GENERATE TRANSACTION ID */
    const transactionId = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(user.uid).collection('transactions').doc().id

    /* CALL INTOUCH API */
    let resp
     try {
         resp = await _.initiateIntouchTransaction(amount, user.phoneNumber, `${user.uid}|${transactionId}`, provider, operation, otp)
     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', 'Intouch transaction failed')
     }
    //If transaction failed, stop execution right here
     if (resp.status !== _.IntouchTransactionStatus.PENDING && resp.status !== _.IntouchTransactionStatus.INITIATED) {
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', 'Intouch transaction failed')
     }

    console.log('response '+resp)

    /* UPDATE LEDGER AND FIRESTORE */
    const batch = _.db.batch()
    const userRef = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(user.uid)
    const transactionRef = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(user.uid).collection('transactions').doc(transactionId)
    console.log('user reference '+userRef)
    console.log('transactionRef '+transactionRef)

    const record: _.TransactionRecord = {
        type: operation === _.IntouchOperation.CASHIN ? _.TransactionType.CASHIN
            : operation === _.IntouchOperation.CASHOUT ? _.TransactionType.CASHOUT
                : operation === _.IntouchOperation.AIRTIME ? _.TransactionType.AIRTIME
                    : _.TransactionType.BILL,
        sender: {
            uid: user.uid,
            handle: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName:  otp
        },
        receiver: {
            uid: '',
            handle: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        },
        amount: amount,
        passPhrase: '',
        status: _.TransactionStatus.ONHOLD,
        ledgerRecords: { first: {}, second: {} },
        intouchResponses: { first: resp, second: {} },
        clientTimestamp: data.clientTimestamp
    }

    //If CASHOUT OR AIRTIME OR BILL, reserve tokens on ledger
    if (operation === _.IntouchOperation.CASHOUT || operation === _.IntouchOperation.AIRTIME || operation === _.IntouchOperation.BILL) {
        //Ledger
        let transaction
        try {
            transaction = await _.writeTransactionToLedger(_.TransactionType.RESERVATION, amount,
                { sourceAccountId: user.uid, destinationAccountId: operation })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Could not write transaction to ledger')
        }

        //Firestore
        record.ledgerRecords.first = transaction
        batch
            .update(userRef, { wallet: { fcfa: user.wallet.fcfa - amount, points: user.wallet.points } })
            .set(transactionRef, record)

    } else if (operation === _.IntouchOperation.CASHIN) {
        //Firestore
        batch.set(transactionRef, record)
    }

    /* WRITE TO FIRESTORE */
     try {
         await batch.commit()
     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Firestore write failed after intouch api call')
     }
})

/**
 * Callback for Intouch
 */
exports.intouchCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { partner_transaction_id, status } = req.body
    if (typeof partner_transaction_id !== 'string' || typeof status !== 'string') { res.end(); return }
console.log(req.body)
    //Extract both from partnerTransactionId
    const [uid, transactionId] = partner_transaction_id.split('|')

    /* LOOKUP USER AND TRANSACTION */
    const user = await _.findUser({ uid: uid })
    if (user === undefined) { res.end(); return }

    const transaction = await _.findTransaction(transactionId, { senderUid: uid })
    if (transaction === undefined) {
        console.log('cannot find transaction')
        res.end(); 
        return 
    }

    /* UPDATE BALANCE ON LEDGER AND FIRESTORE BASED ON STATUS */
    const batch = _.db.batch()
    const userRef = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(uid)
    const transactionRef = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(uid).collection('transactions').doc(transactionId)

    let ledgerRecord
    if (status === _.IntouchTransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
        if (transaction.type === _.TransactionType.CASHIN) {
            //WRITE TO LEDGER
            try {
                ledgerRecord = await _.writeTransactionToLedger(transaction.type, transaction.amount, { destinationAccountId: uid })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.end(); 
                return error
            }
            //Update user balance
            batch.update(userRef, { wallet: { fcfa: user.wallet.fcfa + transaction.amount, points: user.wallet.points } })
            //Update transaction record
            batch.update(transactionRef,
                {
                    status: _.IntouchTransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL,
                    ledgerRecords: { first: ledgerRecord, second: {} },
                    intouchResponses: { first: transaction.intouchResponses.first, second: req.body }
                }
            )
        } else if (transaction.type === _.TransactionType.CASHOUT || transaction.type === _.TransactionType.AIRTIME || transaction.type === _.TransactionType.BILL) {
            //WRITE TO LEDGER
            try {
                ledgerRecord = await _.writeTransactionToLedger(transaction.type, transaction.amount, { sourceAccountId: uid })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.end(); return
            }

            //Update transaction record
            batch.update(transactionRef,
                {
                    status: _.IntouchTransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL,
                    ledgerRecords: { first: transaction.ledgerRecords.first, second: ledgerRecord },
                    intouchResponses: { first: transaction.intouchResponses.first, second: req.body }
                }
            )
        }

    } else if (status === _.IntouchTransactionStatus.FAILED) {
        //Update status and save intouch response in transaction record
        batch.update(transactionRef,
            {
                status: _.IntouchTransactionStatus.FAILED,
                intouchResponses: { first: transaction.intouchResponses.first, second: req.body }
            }
        )

        if (transaction.type === _.TransactionType.CASHOUT || transaction.type === _.TransactionType.AIRTIME || transaction.type === _.TransactionType.BILL) {
            //CANCEL TRANSACTION ON LEDGER
            const operation = transaction.type === _.TransactionType.CASHOUT ? _.IntouchOperation.CASHOUT
                : transaction.type === _.TransactionType.AIRTIME ? _.IntouchOperation.AIRTIME
                    : _.IntouchOperation.BILL
            try {
                ledgerRecord = await _.writeTransactionToLedger(_.TransactionType.CANCELLATION, transaction.amount,
                    { sourceAccountId: uid, destinationAccountId: operation })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.end(); return
            }

            //REVERT BALANCE IN FIRESTORE
            batch
                .update(userRef, { wallet: { fcfa: user.wallet.fcfa + transaction.amount, points: user.wallet.points } })
                .update(transactionRef, { ledgerRecords: { first: transaction.ledgerRecords.first, second: ledgerRecord } })
        }
    } else { res.end(); return }

    //Commit batch
    try {
        await batch.commit()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    /* SEND NOTIFICATION TO USER */
    if (status === _.IntouchTransactionStatus.SUCCESSFUL) {
        try {
            switch (transaction.type) {
                case _.TransactionType.CASHIN: {
                    await _.notify(user.notificationToken, `Votre balance a été creditée de ${transaction.amount}`, '', { transactionId: transactionId })
                    break
                }
                case _.TransactionType.CASHOUT: {
                    await _.notify(user.notificationToken, `Votre balance a été debitée de ${transaction.amount}`, '', { transactionId: transactionId })
                    break
                }
                case _.TransactionType.AIRTIME: {
                    await _.notify(user.notificationToken, `Votre achat de ${transaction.amount} d'unités a réussi`, '', { transactionId: transactionId })
                    break
                }
                /* case _.TransactionType.BILL: {
                    
                } */
                default: {
                    break
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    } else if (status === _.IntouchTransactionStatus.FAILED) {
        try {
            await _.notify(user.notificationToken, `Votre transaction ${transactionId} a echouée`, '', { transactionId: transactionId })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    res.end(); return
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your high level design in pseudo code or narrative?  Am I sensing that there are two incoming REST requests at play here?   One that creates some data that is uncommitted and a second request that tries to update the original data?

Comment: My issue is that the data isnt committed for me some reasons. So I am unable to find it when the call back is triggered.

Comment: Basically I prepare a transaction on postIntouch submit the request to a third party  api then saves the transaction record on a user collection. Once the third party confirm the transaction they send a payload with the transaction Id. That is used to update the transaction on firestore.

Comment: As the document isnt submitted I am unable to find it when I receive confirmation on the callback

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a position to check the code thoroughly, but do you expect

```
 const transactionId = _.db.collection('users-beta').doc(user.uid).collection('transactions').doc().id
```

to add data to firestore. If so, it does not.

You need to do an .add or .set to do this.

Comment: Thanks Philip this line generates a document Id not adding the records at this moment.